# Problemas de formato de fechas al subir la aplicacion Yii2 al servidor

Tags: servidor, formato

Pues en un formulario estoy usando el widget datepicker de kartik, que en localhost funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo subi al servidor, me lanza el error de que el formato de fechas es inválido.

En localhost uso MariaDB (Versión: 10.1.9-MariaDB) que viene con el xampp 3.2.2, en windows 10 
En el servidor MariaDB tambien en Debian 9

Al parecer debe ser algo de configuración en algun lugar que no se donde es.

Como podria solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado

Pues configure en el modelo correspondiente, el formato de fecha igual al que esta en el widget, y ya no me da mas el error